# how to connect to remote MySQL server through c++ builder 2009

Tags: mysql, odbc, c++builder

I use rad studio 2009, MySQL connector ODBC 5.1 and I want to connect to a remote MySQL Server. The server ip that I took is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I tried to connect through Microsoft ODBC Administrator using username and password I have using the following params:

```
 Data Source Name : myodbc
 TCP/IP Server    : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port : 3306
 User             : mydata01
 Password         : *******
 Database         : db1
```

When I click on "Test" I get the error : Connection Failed:[HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'(10060).

Does anyone know what I do wrong? How can I connect???

Thanks..

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,49742

Comment: I've checked all the issues that have in that forum but nothing! I don't know what am I doing wrong. Any suggestion???

Comment: Did you read the last page? **You need to configure your web server  to accept remote connections.** http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,239961#msg-239961